# Can't get the photos of my ex-wife and children while applying for DV lottery

Tags: usa, visa, online-resources

I'm applying for the DV Lottery and can't get the photos of my ex-wife and children. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are they all to be included in your [DV entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Diversity-Visa/DV-Instructions-Translations/dv-2025-instructions-translations/DV-2025_Instructions-faqs.pdf)?

Comment: @Traveller See #14 which says any minor children whether they're included in the application or not. A divorced or legally separated spouse can't be included in the petition (that's in an earlier point).